# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushObject' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Before I give any snippets of code, I want to explain the task that I have to implement.

First of all, every class has many subjects and every class has many students. Every subject and student belongs to one class. Also, every subject and student has many grades. But one grade belongs to one subject and one student.

I wanted first in controller to check if there is one grade with those parameters (student and subject), and then if there is that grade, just update marks property (type of 'array' which I have in app/transforms). So here is controller app/controllers/overviewofstudents.js:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  showS: false,
  mark: "",

  actions:{
    showSubjects(){
      this.toggleProperty('showS');
    },

    insertMark(val, val2){
      var subject2 = this.get('store').peekRecord('subject', val2);
      var student = this.get('store').peekRecord('student', val);
      var mark2 = this.get('mark');

      this.get('store').query('grade', {
        filter: {
          student: student,
          subject: subject2
        }
      }).then(function(mark){
        if(mark == null){
          this.get('store').createRecord('grade', {
            marks: [mark2],
            student: student,
            subject: subject2
          }).save().then(function(grade){
            student.get('marks').pushObject(mark2);
            student.save();
            subject2.get('grades').pushObject(mark2);
            subject2.save();
          });
        }else{
          mark.get('marks').pushObject(mark2);
          mark.save();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And here is app/templates/overviewofstudents.hbs:

```html
<br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<center>

<table>

<h2> Chosen class: {{model.name}} </h2>

<br>

<i> Current students in class: </i> <br>

<ol> 
{{#each model.students as |student|}}
  <li> {{student.firstName}}  {{student.lastName}} </li>
  <button class="choose" {{action 'showSubjects'}}> Show subjects </button>
  {{#if showS}}
    <br> Current subjects in class: 
    {{#each model.subjects as |subject|}}
      <br> <b> {{subject.title}} </b>
       Choose grade: 
      <select onchange={{action (mut mark) value="target.value"}}>
        <option value="1"> 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button {{action 'insertMark' student.id subject.id}}> Insert mark for student </button>
    {{/each}}    
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
  <b> Currently there are no students for the class! </b>
{{/each}}
</ol>

</table>

</center>
```

Comment: Do you know on which pushObject call the error happens? And can you provide the code of your transformation?

Comment: @Igor On the last one: "mark.get('marks').pushObject(mark2);". The Array transform is ok, because I used several times in other functions. But here it is: http://imgur.com/jAJuP5O

Comment: You are doing a "this.get('store').query" which will result in an array of marks instead of just one mark. Try doing "this.get('store').queryRecord" and see if it works then.

Comment: @Igor  so, I've tried that but I receive error:"Assertion Failed: You tried to make a query but your adapter does not implement 'queryRecord'". I am using ember fire, firebase that is. And I searched for this error and I found that we should just put limit: 1 as one of the properties in filter. But when I do that I receive the same error I started with: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushObject' of undefined". So, I think my error is in after that, because I get what I started with. That is I get the same error.

Comment: @Igor it's like I can't get past of first line after else:
mark.get('marks').pushObject(mark2); (40 line)

Comment: @МилошРајковић include model for the `grade` and sample data which is returned from `query('grade')`

Comment: @kumkanillam I will leave you pictures of all my models here. So grade model looks like this http://imgur.com/IGjAsaS , class model looks like this http://imgur.com/ZXQfAIM, student model looks like this http://imgur.com/kdBeL1V, subject model looks like this http://imgur.com/OgT6Wpu  ...

Comment: Have you defined array transform. I beleieve there is no builtin support correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @kumkanillam yeah I have defined a array transform in app/transforms/array.js which works correctly on other examples, so that is not a problem but here is a picture of that (http://imgur.com/jAJuP5O) and here is a new question which summarize what I exactly want to solve (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129122/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-there-is-existing-record-before-creating-new-one)

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing [`query`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Store/methods/query?anchor=query) which returns a Promise, which is resolved with an [AdapterPopulatedRecordArray](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14.4/classes/DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray) which extends [RecordArray](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RecordArray), which extends [ArrayProxy](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy) where you can find all the enumerable methods you can use.
You need to use firstObject of the result , you can find in the below code,

```
insertMark(val, val2) {
    var subject2 = this.get('store').peekRecord('subject', val2);
    var student = this.get('store').peekRecord('student', val);
    var mark2 = this.get('mark');

    this.get('store').query('grade', {
        filter: {
            student: student,
            subject: subject2
        }
    }).then(function(mark) {
        if (mark == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            //Here mark is AdapterPouplatedRecordArray. so please confirm are you receiving the result.
            console.log(' Mark ', mark);
            //You need to use firstObject
            mark.get('firstObject').get('marks').pushObject(mark2);
            mark.get('firstObject').save();
        }
    });
}
```

If this query will return single record always then you can try queryRecord instead of query. For this you need to implement backend to accept and return the response.

Comment: queryRecord is not supported by adapter (firebase), we should instead use property in filter limitToLast : 1 . I am still receiving the same error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" after console.log. Can you please implement if and else command. Not just else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am sorry, that you have to implement it one by one. I am not familiar with ember-data. Just create the record and update all the belongsTo and hasMany later and then save it. `student.get('marks').pushObject(mark2);` -> You haven't defined `marks` in student model,. And also `subject2.get('grades')` -> subject model does not have `grades` attributes defined.

Comment: So I have corrected student property and renamed it to grades and subject model does have grades attribute defined from earlier. Look it once more. I have checked else block it does not working like I wrote in the previous comment. And I don't know if I am writing if block correctly, can I use this.get('store') in if block at all?

Comment: You raised valid point here, you can define store outside and use it inside `then` block or use arrow function like `.then(mark => { //you can use this reference })`

Comment: I tried this its not working. The same error is coming right after else block. Please check this question and see if you can solve it...It is related to this question...Solution to this question would be solution to mine question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129122/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-there-is-existing-record-before-creating-new-one